# Linux Change IDT, how to read offset?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, offset

I am trying to edit linex kernel to change IDT so I wrote the following helping function:

```
#include <asm/desc.h>

unsigned long my_get_gate_offset(gate_desc *gate) {
    unsigned long res = 0;
    return result;
}
```

How can I fill `res` in the following way?

the 16 lower bits should get `offset_low`, the mid 16 `offset_middle` and the higher 32 bits get `offset_high` how this can be done in C?

Plus how can I reach `offset_low`, `offset_middle` and `offset_high`? they are declared in `gate_struct` not in `gate_desc`

Comment: is my question clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

There already is the function [`gate_offset`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/desc_defs.h#L97) which does exactly what you ask for:

```
static inline unsigned long gate_offset(const gate_desc *g)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
    return g->offset_low | ((unsigned long)g->offset_middle << 16) |
        ((unsigned long) g->offset_high << 32);
#else
    return g->offset_low | ((unsigned long)g->offset_middle << 16);
#endif
}
```

Comment: can you kindly explain a little? what | means here? why we converted middle to (unsigned long) while offset_low not?

Comment: |: [Bitwise inclusive OR operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.12); offset_low need not be promoted to greater width because it is not shifted left.

Comment: but doing so won't have any impact too

Comment: Right, the compiler will possibly produce the same code.

Comment: Yes, the compiler will promote the `g->offset_low` also to unsigned long when doing the bitwise inclusive OR, due to C integer promotion rules.  The reason the casts are needed for the bit shifts is that `g->offset_middle` is 16-bit, and `g->offset_high` 32-bit, and we need to promote them to the final type *before* shifting the bits, to get the correct/full result.  I like how Armali's code does it, and would use the same code myself.

Comment: Thanks for the laurels, but it's not my code, it's from the Linux kernel. :-)

Comment: @Armali Small questions, why they didn't simple union all those offsets in one part, I don't understand what's the advantage of splitting them. Plus, what does offset mean, why we need it?

Comment: Who do you mean by _they_? The structure of an IDT entry is defined by the processor architecture; see [Interrupt Descriptor Table](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table).